# Unity 2D respawning Instantiate issue

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, unity3d-2dtools

I am making a 2D Space-invaders style game and am having GREAT difficulty with respawning. What i want to happen is when the SpaceShip is hit, it gets Destroyed, e.x. Destroy();

But when i try to Instantiate() the Prefab of the SpaceShip it does the (clone)(clone) problem, so I am trying to Make an Empty GameObject run script that spawns in a Prefab of the SpaceShip, AND when it gets Destroy(); it respawns after 3 seconds. Much help appreciated, and i'm coding in JavaScript.

Comment: I am using STRICT 2D

Comment: (clone)(clone) problem? What gameobject are you passing to Instantiate? It sounds like you're instantiating by reference to the gameobject in the scene rather than from your assets folder.

Comment: I'm trying to Instantiate a prefab from my assets, and the clone problem is not an issue anymore i'm just trying to Instantiate my SpaceShip Prefab from a Empty GameObject's script when the game starts, and when the SpaceShip Prefab gets Destroy();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have one class that instantiates every couple of seconds from a prefab. You will need to drag via the *Editor* the `playerPrefab` and you will need to specify the location for the spawn.

```
public class Spawner : Monobehaviour
{
    public GameObject playerPrefab;

    public void spawn()
    {
        Instantiate(playerPrefab, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
    }
}
```

Then when your `Player` dies you can a `SendMessage` to the `Spawner` class.

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        if(hp <= 0)
        {
             // Grab the reference to the Spawner class.
             GameObject spawner = GameObject.Find("Spawner");

             // Send a Message to the Spawner class which calls the spawn() function.
             spawner.SendMessage("spawn");
             Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Same code in `UnityScript`

Spawner.js

```
  var playerPrefab : GameObject;

  function spawn()
  {
      Instantiate(playerPrefab, spawnPosition, spawnRotation);
  }
```

Player.js

```
  function Update()
  {
      if(hp <= 0)
      {
          // Grab the reference to the Spawner class.
          var spawner : GameObject = GameObject.Find("Spawner");

          // Send a Message to the Spawner class which calls the spawn() function.
          spawner.SendMessage("spawn");
          Destroy(gameObject);
      }
  }
```

Comment: the only problem is, I don't want the Prefab to be spawned every couple of seconds, just when i start and when it gets Destroy();

Comment: Do i put this in the Start() or Update()?

Comment: btw: I just want the SpaceShip to Destroy() i have already dealt with the enemy

Comment: I thought the SpaceShip was the enemy, well it is the same principal.

Comment: have you played Space Invaders XD

Comment: GameObject spawner = GameObject.Find("Spawner");
             spawner.SendMessage("spawn");

Comment: It finds the `Spawner` GameObject in the scene then calls the `spawn()` function. By the way, you are using `UnityScript` right? My code above is in `C#`

Comment: Again, Where do i put this? Start() or Update()?

Comment: I have it in the `Update()` you could put it anywhere that indicates when the player dies.

Comment: Could you change this to JavaScript?

Comment: @hudson I just did. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a ton! You were a great help!

Comment: One more thing, when you put Player.js and Spawner.js What are those? Is the spawner.js the Empty GameObject the i'm using to un script? And is the Player.js the SpaceShip script?

Comment: Yes, `Spawner.js` is a script attached to an Empty GameObject named Spawner in the *Editor*. And `Player.js` is your SpaceShip script.